# What characters can des(unix) have?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, des

All lowercase and uppercase, all digits, dot and slash.
Have I missed anything?

This seems like an very easy question found to find at Google but actually I haven't found any information about it :(

Edit, if anybody missunderstod, what characters can the OUTPUT have.
I'm not asking what kind of stuff I can hash, I'm asking what the hash looks like.

Comment: This isn't clear; DES simply encrypts bytes to bytes.

Comment: What's also not clear is which des (command, library subroutine, call, ...) on which UNIX.  e.g. [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/mann/des.n.html).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I assume this is about the DES crypt password hash, not about the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

DES (and many other encryption algorithms) work on a bit level - it has no concept of what's a valid character and what isn't, the range of the output characters can be anything from 0x00 to 0xFF.

Any output to the contrary is likely just characters not supported by whatever you're trying to display the output with, which are typically replaced by some predefined character.

The output can also be converted to hex characters for cosmetic or storage purposes (I'm not sure whether the `des` command would do this - it's simple enough to see by just running it), e.g. a single 'a' (0x61) character will be converted to two characters: '61'. The resulting output characters would thus be in the range `A`-`F` or `a`-`f` and `0`-`9`.

Note that [keys require ASCII](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?des+1), but this is not a requirement of DES itself, as can be derived from "Bugs" on the same page, and it doesn't affect the range of output values.

Answer (score 0):

The DES algorithm is considered obsolete and unsafe. The DES standard (FIPS 46-3) has been withdrawn in 2005.

Use at your own risk.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard